# How to compare two rows from different excel's into one new excel in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I am starting to program in vb.net and I am making a program that takes values ​​from excel columns of 2 files and shows results in a generated excel.

so the first excel has this columns: delivery number, contentID, packages, volume. the second excel has this columns:SPS Number, folder number, contentID, packages, volume.

the excel that i have to generato has this columns:SPS number,folder number, delivery number, contentID,packages, volume. The excel that i have to generate with the program uses contentID as the main identificator, and it has ti compare the packages and volume if the ContentID is the same.

so far i have this in a funtions file:

```
Module Funciones

'VARIABLES REMATE'
Public ENTREGA As New List(Of String)
Public PAQUETE As New List(Of String)
Public CONTENEDOR As New List(Of String)
Public VOLUMEN As New List(Of String)



'VARIABLES PLANILLA'

Public NSPS As New List(Of String)
Public NPLANILLA As New List(Of String)
Public PAQUETE2 As New List(Of String)
Public IDCONTENEDOR As New List(Of String)
Public VOLUMEN2 As New List(Of String)


Public Sub INICIALIZAR_PLANILLA(ByRef HOJAUSUARIOS As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet)
    Try
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("A1").Value = "N° SPS"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("B1").Value = "N° PLANILLA"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("C1").Value = "ENTREGA"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("D1").Value = "CONTENEDOR"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("E1").Value = "PAQUETES"
        HOJAUSUARIOS.Cells("F1").Value = "VOLUMEN"

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function seleccionardirectorio(ByVal filtro As String) As String

    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = filtro
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Seleccione Directorio"
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Return saveFileDialog1.FileName
End Function


Function extraer_valores_remate(ByRef ruta As String) As Boolean
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
    Try

        Dim stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(ruta)
        Dim package = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(stream)
        '//  Libro
        Dim Workbook = package.Workbook
        '//  Hojas
        Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets
        ' Dim aux As Integer = 1
        'While (Workbook.Worksheets.Count >= aux)
        Dim hojaUsuarios = Workbook.Worksheets(Workbook.Worksheets.Item(0).ToString)
        Dim indice As Integer = 2

        While (indice < 2000)
            'Numero entrega'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                ENTREGA.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value)
            End If
            'Numero Contenedor'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("B" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                CONTENEDOR.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("B" & indice).Value)
            End If
            'Paquete'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("C" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                PAQUETE.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("C" & indice).Value)
            End If
            'Volumen'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("D" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                VOLUMEN.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("D" & indice).Value)
            End If

            indice += 1
        End While
        indice += 1

    Catch EX As Exception
        MsgBox(EX.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True

End Function

Function extraer_valores_planilla(ByRef ruta As String) As Boolean
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
    Try
        Dim stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(ruta)
        Dim package = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(stream)
        '//  Libro
        Dim Workbook = package.Workbook
        '//  Hojas
        Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets

        ' While (Workbook.Worksheets.Count >= aux)
        Dim hojaUsuarios = Workbook.Worksheets(Workbook.Worksheets.Item(0).ToString)
        Dim indice As Integer = 2

        While (indice < 5000)
            'Numero entrega'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                NSPS.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value)
            End If
            'Numero Contenedor'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("B" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                NPLANILLA.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("B" & indice).Value)
            End If
            'Paquete'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("C" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                IDCONTENEDOR.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("C" & indice).Value)

            End If
            'Volumen'
            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("D" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                PAQUETE2.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("D" & indice).Value)
            End If

            If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("E" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                VOLUMEN2.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("E" & indice).Value)
            End If

            indice += 1
        End While
        indice += 1
    Catch EX As Exception
        MsgBox(EX.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True

End Function
Public Sub LIMPIAR_VARIABLES_REMATE()
    ENTREGA.Clear()
    CONTENEDOR.Clear()
    PAQUETE.Clear()
    VOLUMEN.Clear()
End Sub

Public Sub LIMPIAR_VARIABLES_PLANILLA()
    ENTREGA.Clear()
    CONTENEDOR.Clear()
    PAQUETE.Clear()
    VOLUMEN.Clear()
End Sub
```

and on the main file i have this

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions Imports OfficeOpenXml Imports OfficeOpenXml.Style

Public Class Form1 Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    OFD.Title = "Selecciona un archivo"
    OFD.Filter = "XLSX|*.xlsx"
    If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(OFD.FileName)
        Dim nombreOriginal As String = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(OFD.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = nombreOriginal
        extraer_valores_remate(nombreOriginal)
        Button4.Enabled = True
        Button3.Enabled = True
    Else
        MsgBox("Campo Requerido", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Title:="Faltan Datos")
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If

End Sub

Public nombre_archivo As String = ""

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    OFD.Title = "Selecciona un archivo"
    OFD.Filter = "XLSX|*.xlsx"
    If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(OFD.FileName)
        nombre_archivo2 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OFD.FileName)
        Dim nombreOriginal As String = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(OFD.FileName)
        TextBox2.Text = nombreOriginal
        extraer_valores_planilla(nombreOriginal)

    Else
        MsgBox("Campo Requerido", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Title:="Faltan Datos")
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Public nombre_archivo2 As String = ""

'********VARIABLES EXCEL DE CARGA**********'
'Public ENTREGA As New List(Of String)
'Public IDCONTENEDOR As New List(Of String)
''Public PAQUETES As New List(Of String)
'Public VOLUMEN As New List(Of String)
'Public NSPS As New List(Of String)
'Public NPLANILLA As New List(Of String)
'Public IDCONTENERDOR2 As New List(Of String)
'' Public PAQUETES2 As New List(Of String)
'Public VOLUMEN2 As New List(Of String)


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    LIMPIAR_VARIABLES_REMATE()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    MsgBox("Las variables del remate se han limpiado correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="LIMPIAR")

End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
    Dim path As String = seleccionardirectorio("Excel|.xlsx")
    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) = False) Then

        Dim excel = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(path))
        excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hoja1")
        Dim aux As Integer = 1
        Dim Workbook = excel.Workbook
        Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets

        Dim hoja1 = Workbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
        'DAMOS NOMBRE A LAS COLUMNAS 
        INICIALIZAR_PLANILLA(hoja1)

        While (aux <= CONTENEDOR.Count)

            hoja1.Cells("C" & aux + 1).Value = ENTREGA.Item(aux - 1)
            aux += 1
        End While
        aux = 1

        While (aux <= IDCONTENEDOR.Count)

            hoja1.Cells("A" & aux + 1).Value = NSPS.Item(aux - 1)


            aux += 1
        End While
        aux = 1

        While (aux <= IDCONTENEDOR.Count)

            hoja1.Cells("B" & aux + 1).Value = NPLANILLA.Item(aux - 1)
            aux += 1
        End While
        aux = 1

        While (aux <= IDCONTENEDOR.Count)

            hoja1.Cells("D" & aux + 1).Value = IDCONTENEDOR.Item(aux - 1)


            aux += 1
        End While
        aux = 1

        While (aux <= IDCONTENEDOR.Count)

            hoja1.Cells("E" & aux + 1).Value = PAQUETE2.Item(aux - 1)

            aux += 1
        End While
        aux = 1

        While (aux <= IDCONTENEDOR.Count)

            hoja1.Cells("F" & aux + 1).Value = VOLUMEN2.Item(aux - 1)

            'Cambiar color de la celda ocupar este codigo'

            'hoja1.Cells("A" & aux + 1).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            'hoja1.Cells("A" & aux + 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red)


            aux += 1
        End While
        aux = 1

        excel.Save()
        MsgBox("Documento Creado Correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Operacion Correcta")
        Process.Start(path)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    LIMPIAR_VARIABLES_PLANILLA()
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    MsgBox("Las variables de la planilla se han limpiado correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="LIMPIAR")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

so as you can this does not compare the two excel and it just shows me information

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error? It seems more like a logic type of error that you cannot figure out rather than a specific error/exception, and in that case it might help to go write some PSUEO CODE to figure out 1) how you are gong to loop through both files and 2) how you are going to compare fields and 3) how you are going to write to the new Excel file once you find a match.

Comment: i guess i want some example of comparative between 2 excel in vb.net because i am new to the language

Comment: I'm with @JohnPete22 on this.  You need to forget about trying to code this for now and work out the logic including the comparison criteria before attempting to code things.  Also, while I commend you on translating your question, please be aware sometimes your code might need a little explanation for us too

Answer (score 0):

you need to match the rows by combining 2 loops.

```
For each itemfromfile1 in file1
    for each itemfromfile2 in file2
         ' Match 2 rows with each other
         if itemfromfile1.SomeField = itemfromfile2.SomeField then
              ' These are the linked rows between the 2 documents 
         end if
    next
next
```

Simple fill in the pseudo variables with the code that your office implementation uses.